# error when trying to release a Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

When you try to release the project, Flex gives me the following:

> Flash Builder program failed to publish the source code of the
>   project: Unable to find the application file "betaProject4.mxml".
>   Could not find the application file "betaProject4.mxml".

Currently in a project of this file is not found, removed all of the bin-release, but something did not work. Thank in advance.

Comment: Please provide more details.  How are you trying to create a release build?  With Flash Builder?  How is your project structured?  Are you sure that beatPRoject4.mxml the name of a file in project?  Are you trying to include the source?

Comment: Yes by Flash Builder, project in this file is not included.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open `.actionScriptProperties` file in your project's directory with text editor. And then try to find `betaProject4.mxml` in `<applications>` section of this file. If it found, remove all `<application />` line with this file.

Comment: I was there in the first place checked this line is not found(((

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue coming out of the blue suddenly. Tried all kinds of tricks found in the web of editing, adding additional applications etc but none of them worked. However the only one which worked was this:

1. Delete the project from FB (but don't delete contents)
2. Close and reopen FB
3. Import the project again from the repo
4. Clean and export release build.

Speculation: the project entry in the Eclipse gets corrupted and reimporting makes it again from clean.